# Why would NSWindow with NSTableView not resize?

Tags: cocoa

Here is my IB setup:

http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/5929/picture1gxr.png

When both `NSScrollView` and `NSTableView` are set to autoresize and autofill (all the arrows in the Autosizing section are checked) my window does not resize. Actually it resizes, but by a pixel, as if it remembers that it is not supposed to resize after I start dragging the corner. If I uncheck the autofill arrows (disabling `NSViewWidthSizable` and `NSViewHeightSizable`) on the `NSScrollView`, the window resizes fine, but of course, the scroll view does not resize with it.

The weird thing is that in the situation where the window is "rigid" if I resize one of the `NSTableView`'s columns beyond the view (thus causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear), I can resize the window but only until it reaches the size big enough to accommodate all the columns and then becomes rigid again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I've reverted to my last good commit and rebuilt the view hierarchy and everything worked. It is probably a bug in `BWSplitView`, but I can't reproduce it anymore, so can't report really.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have set a fixed minimum/maximum size for the window?

Comment: That wouldn't be affected by the scroll view or table view, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a feature or bug of BWSplitView? What if you make it an NSSplitView?

If it turns out to be a bug, you should [report it](https://bitbucket.org/bwalkin/bwtoolkit/issues/).